# findItemsByCategory filter response by country- ebay api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to filter ebay response of "findItemsByCategory" with country domain value "EBAY-GB" (This is for UK site) But problem is even i add this code with AddHeader i am getting US ebay site response. Any idea to filter by country code of ebay?

[Documentation1](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsByCategory.html)
[Documentation2](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/SiteIDToGlobalID.html)

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByCategory&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YourAppID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId=10181&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2

```
public ActionResult Search(string categoryId)
        {
            //api configs

            string OperationName = "findItemsByCategory";
            string AppId = "KloinHkm-B-PRD-6bf1-97d25";

            string Url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME="+OperationName+"&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME="+AppId+"&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId="+categoryId+"&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=110";
            var client = new RestClient(Url);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.Method = Method.GET;
            request.AddHeader("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-GB");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            //request.AddParameter("application/json", obj, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request).Content;



            return View();
        }
```